# Incorrect Syntax Near `=` - SQL Expression

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to include a conditional check in a `WHERE` statement.But i keep getting Invalid expression at `= 3`

```
WHERE APCCL.data = @coolval
          AND CCMF.Status_ID = 1
          AND APCCL.Status_ID = 1
          AND CLM.myval = 3
          AND 
          CASE APEL.numval
          WHEN 1 THEN  CLM.value =  3 END
```

Basically i want to check CLM.VALUE=3 when APEL.numval=1 otherwise this AND Condition should not be executed.

Comment: Please do [not crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/157328) already asked and answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64709766

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this , if I understood it right :

```
WHERE APCCL.data = @coolval
          AND CCMF.Status_ID = 1
          AND APCCL.Status_ID = 1
          AND 
          ( 
             (CLM.myval = 3 and APEL.numval = 1)
           or
             (APEL.numval <> 1 )
          )
```

or try to split in 2 :

```
SELECT ...
WHERE APCCL.data = @coolval
          AND CCMF.Status_ID = 1
          AND APCCL.Status_ID = 1
          AND CLM.myval = 3 
          AND APEL.numval = 1

UNION  ALL  /* or UNION */

SELECT ...
WHERE APCCL.data = @coolval
          AND CCMF.Status_ID = 1
          AND APCCL.Status_ID = 1
          AND APEL.numval <> 1
```

Here are some sample testing:

```
declare @coolVal int = 1;

SELECT *
FROM 
(
SELECT 1 as Data, 1 as Status_ID , 3 as myVal, 1 as numVal UNION ALL
SELECT 1 as Data, 1 as Status_ID , 3 as myVal, 2 as numVal UNION ALL
SELECT 1 as Data, 1 as Status_ID , 4 as myVal, 1 as numVal UNION ALL
SELECT 1 as Data, 1 as Status_ID , 4 as myVal, 2 as numVal 
)a
WHERE
      data = @coolVal
          AND Status_ID = 1
          AND Status_ID = 1
          AND 
    ( 
        (myval = 3 and numval = 1)
        or
        (numval <> 1) 
    )
```

or with UNION

```
declare @coolVal int = 1;

SELECT *
FROM 
(
SELECT 1 as Data, 1 as Status_ID , 3 as myVal, 1 as numVal UNION ALL
SELECT 1 as Data, 1 as Status_ID , 3 as myVal, 2 as numVal UNION ALL
SELECT 1 as Data, 1 as Status_ID , 4 as myVal, 1 as numVal UNION ALL
SELECT 1 as Data, 1 as Status_ID , 4 as myVal, 2 as numVal 
)a
WHERE
          data = @coolVal
          AND Status_ID = 1
          AND Status_ID = 1
          AND myval = 3 
          and numval = 1
    
UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM 
(
SELECT 1 as Data, 1 as Status_ID , 3 as myVal, 1 as numVal UNION ALL
SELECT 1 as Data, 1 as Status_ID , 3 as myVal, 2 as numVal UNION ALL
SELECT 1 as Data, 1 as Status_ID , 4 as myVal, 1 as numVal UNION ALL
SELECT 1 as Data, 1 as Status_ID , 4 as myVal, 2 as numVal 
)a
WHERE
          data = @coolVal
          AND Status_ID = 1
          AND Status_ID = 1
          AND numval <> 1
```

and the result set :

```
Data    Status_ID   myVal   numVal
1       1          3        1
1       1          3        2
1       1          4        2
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=774a8804f25f0f8a0c2478226d71e3bc)

some interesting info [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/07/t-sql-queries/table-expressions-part-4)